# Add multiple labels in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following label:

```
<Label Text="{x:Static local:FontAwesome.FACheck}" FontFamily="FontAwesome" TextColor="Green"/>
```

And an event on button:

```
correctButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
{
   App.DB.IncrementScore();
};
```

What this does is everytime I click on a button my score is incremented by 1. What I wanted to do is also increment the number of `Label`s depending on the number of score. See the attached image below:

[image]

Anyone has any idea how I could achieve this?

Comment: I would strongly recommend looking into an MVVM architecture for this app. You can bind your labels to an `ObservableCollection <string>` in your ViewMidel.

Comment: @RobLyndon thanks. I know about MVVM but I don't know how to apply it here. Can you give me some code sample relating to my issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are different solutions to this question. Be sure to read through all of them before choosing one - my favorite (the simplest one) is listed all the way down...

**Approach #1:**

As several people have suggested, you can create some collection control (I'll come to that in a moment), define an `ObservableCollection` within a ViewModel, set the Page's `Binding Context` to an instance of that ViewModel, and add items to the collection on button click:

```
public class MyViewModel()
{
    public ObservableCollection<int> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>();
}

private MyViewModel _viewModel = new MyViewModel();
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = _viewModel;
}

correctButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
{
    App.DB.IncrementScore();
    _viewModel.Items.Add(0);
};
```

The type of `ObservableCollection` actually does not matter, since we are using the same static `ItemTemplate` for all items:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ScoreItemTemplate">
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
                <Label Text="{x:Static local:FontAwesome.FACheck}" FontFamily="FontAwesome" TextColor="Green"/>
            </ViewCell.View>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

The main problem with this approach is that Xamarin.Forms `ListView` can not display its items horizontally. This means, you'd need to download one of the available `HorizontalListView` Nuget packages out there, or use the [built-in (only in Xamarin.Forms 2.3 and above!) `CarouselView`](https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/):

```
<CarouselView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ScoreItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
```

Then, you'll might wish to spend some time removing all the visual effects for swiping through the carousel, and for selecting items if you choose to use a horizontal ListView...

Instead, there are two alternative solutions that involve less effort:

**Approach #2:**

Obviously, the simple approach would be to create the "template" label in code:

```
private Label CreateScoreLabel()
{
    return new Label {Text = FontAwesome.FACheck, TextColor = Color.Green, FontFamily = "FontAwesome"};
}
```

...add a horizontal `StackLayout` to the page:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="LabelStack"/>
```

...and add new labels the hard way:

```
correctButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
{
    App.DB.IncrementScore();
    LabelStack.Children.Add(CreateScoreLabel());
};
```

However, all this seems rather hacky for just creating a list of green check marks. This leads us to...

**...approach #3:**

Technically, this isn't exactly what you asked for (*increment the number of Labels*), but according to your screen shot it might fulfill your needs in a much simpler way.

Remove the existing label's text (as it shall display nothing at startup), and instead give it a unique name:

```
<Label x:Name="ScoreLabel" FontFamily="FontAwesome" TextColor="Green"/>
```

Now, define a simple extension method for the `string` type that repeats a given string for a certain number of times:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Repeat(this string input, int num)
    {
        return String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(input, num));
    }
}
```

(There are multiple ways to make this *repeat* function as performant as possible, I simply chose the simplest one-liner available, search StackOverflow for detailed discussions...)

You can now work with the single `Label` control defined in XAML, and just assign several check marks to it on button click:

```
correctButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
{
    App.DB.IncrementScore();
    ScoreLabel.Text = FontAwesome.FACheck.Repeat(App.DB.Score); // replace parameter by whatever method allows you to access the current score number
};
```

Of course, this approach can also be adapted to follow the MMVM way, by simply using a public bindable `string` property instead of setting the label's `Text` attribute directly, but for this I'd advise you to take a look at a beginner's MVVM tutorial.

Comment: thanks. Im trying out approach #3 but im getting an error `string was not recognized as a valid boolean`. Any idea why?

Comment: At which line is this error thrown? Also, can you show the exact button click handler after adapting it to match your needs?

Comment: Sorry its my mistake. I have added a `IsVisible` property in my label while I was tinkering with code earlier but left the value empty. I will work on the code more with your solution then let you know when it works.

Comment: Definitely use approach #3, you will save a lot on performance from reducing the number of Labels. Possibly creating 5 labels to create 5 checks is overkill. This also removes the need of a horizontal `StackLayout` or `CarouselView` and you can use the `Label` spacing options to place the checks. Approach 3 should be marked as the answer and the question should be modified appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Simply insert new label code in button click event which will add new children in your score stack.

cs page Code:-

```
button.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
    {
        App.DB.IncrementScore();
        lblStack.Children.Add(new Label {Text = FontAwesome.FACheck, TextColor = Color.Green, FontFamily = "FontAwesome"});
    };
```

xamal code

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="lblStack"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the score has a maximum just add the max number of labels and bind their visibility.

Or you can make a listview of labels and bind the source to a collection that you increment when required.

Comment: I could do this but its not a very clean solution as I have max number of 20 points.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not sure if this answer is correct, but it's too long for a comment. Just test it and if it doesn't work I will delete this answer

---

You can add controls programmatically. Keep in mind that you need to add a `Label` on your MainThread, because it's a change to the UI. Add this to your `Clicked` event:

```
correctButton.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
{
    App.DB.IncrementScore();
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => // On MainThread because it's a change in your UI
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = "{x:Static local:FontAwesome.FACheck}"; // Not sure if this is right syntax...
        label.FontFamily = "FontAwesome";
        label.TextColor = Color.Green;
        stackPanel.Children.Add(label);
    });
};
```

In case you have a `Grid`, you can set `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` with the `SetValue` method of a `Control`:

```
label.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 1);
label.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 2);
```